# installing woocommerce connector in odoo

Tags: wordpress, python-2.7, woocommerce, odoo

i want to connect woocommerce and odoo. i have problem with woocommmerce connector installation in Odoo. i got the woocommerce connector from https://github.com/OCA/connector-woocommerce . i have upload this module into addons folder in odoo.. When i tried to update the module list in odoo, i got this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 537, in _handle_exception
        return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception).
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 574, in dispatch
        result = self._call_function(**self.params)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 310, in _call_function
        return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
       return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 307, in checked_call
       return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 803, in __call__
       return self.method(*args, **kw)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 403, in response_wrap
       response = f(*args, **kw)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 948, in call_button
       action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
       return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
       return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 393, in old_api
       result = new_api(recs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 397, in new_api
       result = [method(rec, *args, **kwargs) for rec in self]
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/module/wizard/base_module_update.py", line 15, in update_module
       self.updated, self.added = self.env['ir.module.module'].update_list()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 239, in wrapper
       return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 462, in new_api
       result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 654, in update_list
       handler.load_addons()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 1308, in load_addons
       m = __import__('openerp.addons.' + module)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/module.py", line 80, in load_module
       mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/connector_woocommerce/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
       from . import model
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/connector_woocommerce/model/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
       from . import backend
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/connector_woocommerce/model/backend.py", line 23, in <module>
       from woocommerce import API

    ImportError: No module named woocommerce
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you do not have installed `woocommerce REST api` on your system.

install woocommerce using your terminal. here is the command

```
sudo pip install woocommerce
```

EDIT:

Open python prompt in terminal

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from woocommerce import API
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named woocommerce
```

If it says **No module named woocommerce** means you have some installation issue with woocommerce.

Comment: I already install woocommerce in Ubuntu server.. But still get the same error when trying to update the module list

Comment: try to import "from woocommerce import API" from python terminal.

Comment: How to import the woocommerce import api

Comment: I already tried to import api using your command line ">>> from woocommerce import API" and there is no error like you mention above. Does this mean the installation went right for the module. Is there any other solution you can help me with?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem while installing woocommerce connector in odoo. After that i have installed woocommerce module by

`pip install woocommerce`. I was working on windows platform.

I was getting same problem after successfully installing woocommerce python module.

**Here Problem is odoo is not finding woocommerce in it's addon folder.**

**So solution is here  :**

> - open folder "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages".
> - This is the path where python modules are installed. From this folder find the folder 'woocommerce'.
> - copy this folder and put this in odoo server path which is
> - "D:\Odoo 8.0-20160107\server" .
> - Now restart odoo

Hope this will help you.