# Install WooCommerce connector on odoo 9.0

Tags: woocommerce, odoo

I would like to install WooCommerce connector in Odoo 9.0 and it doesn't work.
About technical information, it's under Debian Jessie.

Odoo is install with an:

```
sudo apt-get install odoo
```

And it works.
WooCommerce connector is installed with an:

```
 sudo easy_install woocommerce
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34892876/installing-woocommerce-connector-in-odoo), woocommerce is installed in Python part because It's possible to execute:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from woocommerce import API
```

without any error.

At the end, WooCommerce module isn't displayed in application list in Odoo.

If somebody have an idea and can explain, it will be appreciate.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is response received from modules developpers:

> Yeah, the module is not migrated to v9, so it doesn't work in this version until it is.

According to discussion on gitub, some dependent modules are not yet migrated.

Comment: Have you also downloaded its dependent module ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to download odoo-woocommerce connector module from the git link [Odoo-woocommerce connector](https://github.com/OCA/connector-woocommerce/tree/9.0) or Download it from odoo apps website [Odoo-woocommerce connector](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/connector_woocommerce/).

Once downloaded, upload that folder/modules in Odoo addons directory. Than you have to go to Odoo application list and need to click on Upgrade Apps List menu. Once Upgraded, you will see the apps in Apps list menu.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nilesh for your feedback,

I already try to do this and it doesn't work but may I made a mistake ?

Odoo app website provide a woo connector for 8.0 version (2nd link), so I downloaded OCA version (1st link).
I placed, connector_woocommerce directory (directory placed in connector_woocommerce-9.0 directory) in

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons

directory.

I performed "Upgrade Apps List" on Odoo and .... nothing happen.

Does somebody already try this ?